# Monitor goes black for a few seconds

Tags: troubleshooting, display, kvm-switch

I have a Hanns G 28" monitor, Model # HG281D

It has its issues (viewing angle sucks) but has been functional and solid, great for desktop stuff.  Worked without any sign of any problems for 6-12 months.

However, now the monitor "goes black" for about 2-3 seconds, almost like when you click "detect display"

- It does not turn off (power light does not go amber)
- The computer is completely unaffected and the video mode never changes when the picture returns.
- The computer is fully responsive and will keep playing music or taking my keypresses during the time I can't see anything. (it just happened and I kept typing, etc)
- It happens on multiple computers across several operating systems. (I have an 8-port iogear KVM switch that has several computers connected)
- But, it seems to happen **only on certain computers**.  I have a hackintosh that does it, a windows 7 PC that does not, a lenovo laptop that does not, and my old ubuntu 8.10 box did not do it, but my new mint 8 box does do it.
- I've check the connections and tried changing out the power cable and the vga cable.
- Sometimes it won't happen for hours (or days) and sometimes it happens several times per hour.  It was happening many months ago, did not happen for months, and has now started happening again.

Does this make any sense?  What could it be?

Comment: Have you tried sans kvm on the affected computers?

Comment: Try quickly setting the brightness to 0 as soon as you turn on the computer. If the screen stays on, let me know and I'll post the answer.